# Визуальное программирование для Android

Tags: android

Необходимо приложение для андроид, компании требуют 270тыс.р, до этого я занимался только веб-программированием. Узнал о всех инструментах для создания приложений, остановился на Eclipce+PhoneGap. Но тут сразу встретил проблему, это огромное бесчисленное кол-во css классов для элементов в jquery mobile UI. Было так неудобно что даже горизонтальную форму поиска тяжело было уместить, всё двигалось очень долго, и я решил узнать о других фреймворках, практически все UI ведут себя отвратительно, и тут я наткнулся на инструмент http://www.applicationcraft.com, отличное визуальное построение элементов, и другие классные плюшечки, но там нужно тоже есть свои нюансы. И тут возник вопрос. Есть ли какие-нить инструменты для eclipce+PhoneGap позволяющие так же визуально всё редактировать, потом просто смотреть исходники html5+css3+js(jquery), IDE вобщем для PG.???

Как ещё может веб-программист сделать приложение для Андроид?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А мне нравится [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Прога супер. Программы для IOS и ANDROID. Только жаль, что не знаю, как там с GUI.

А выучить можно [здесь](http://www.lynda.com/Titanium-training/Mobile-App-Development-Essential-Training/89116-2.html).

Comment: Попробую его, но тема была про IDE для PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

У нас в компании усиленно продвигают RhoMobile. Та часть, которая отвечает за собственно клиента (Rhodes) бесплатна и открыта. Принцип построения MVC на основе HTML+CSS+JS. Переносима между iPhone, Android, RIM, Windows Mobile и Windows Phone 7. При желании можно разрабатывать в облаке. Для веб-разработчика может быть интересно.

Comment: Он я так понимаю с Ruby завязан?

Comment: Да, там плотная завязка на Ruby.

Comment: Боюсь что с Ruby, я не знаком.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha touch?